# How to sort an array in an unusual way

Tags: php

I went to an interview today, and got asked this PHP question.

How do I write a program to sort this array

FROM:

```
$my_arr = array(2, 45, 15, 75, 12, 99);
```

TO:

```
$my_new_arr = array(2, 99, 12, 75, 15, 45);  // (smallest, largest, second smallest, second largest, third smallest, third largest)
```

The manager only gave me 12 minutes to work on it before the next interviewer came in. I was stuck(still am) so I couldn't do it.

Comment: Since you don't even know that PHP variables begin with `$`, maybe this test was a little too advanced for you.

Comment: Fair... What stops you from spending some time to show what you tried?

Comment: Agreed. In 12 minutes you must have come up with _something_. Let's see what you did.

Comment: Sort the array. Then take the first element, last element, 2nd element, 2nd-to-last element, and so on until you reach the middle.

Comment: barmar :) yeah I got confused with Perl.

Comment: @Barmar - sure, but you failed the question as asked by OP: title talks about 2 arrays, but shows one meaning one who answer need to ask more questions first :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question only asks about sorting one array. I think he just made a mistake in his title.

Comment: sorry my first post here. I corrected the title, and changed from @my_arr to $my_arr. I did walk him thru my thought process but I got stuck. basically i recreated two new arrays, one with sort, one with reverse sort. Then do a for() loop for the first sort array, then I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4):

The functions [array_shift](http://php.net/array_shift) and [array_pop](http://php.net/array_pop) will be useful for your purpose:

```
$my_arr = array(2, 45, 15, 75, 12, 99);
sort($my_arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
$my_new_arr = array();
$func = "array_shift";
while(sizeof($my_arr)){
    // as long as there are elements in the array
$my_new_arr[] = $func($my_arr);
    // apply either “array_shift” or “array_pop” to the array
$func = ($func == "array_shift") ? "array_pop" : "array_shift";
    // change “array_shift” to “array_pop” and “array_pop” to “array_shift” for the next iteration
}
print_r($my_new_arr);
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 99
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 75
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 45
)
```

Comment: Gotta +1 this -  It's a little opaque for such a simple problem and doesn't really result in more concise code, but using variable functions and ternary operators is a pretty good way of demonstrating competency on a simple problem... and given that the OP cited it as an interview question, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to **@Barmar**'s comment:

> Sort the array. Then take the first element, last element, 2nd element, 2nd-to-last element, and so on until you reach the middle.

You might implement something like this with help of [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort), [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array-pop) and [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array-shift):

```
$array = array(2, 45, 15, 75, 12, 99);

sort($array);

$result = array();

while($array){
    $result[] = array_shift($array);

    if(!$array)break;

    $result[] = array_pop($array);
}

print_r($result);
```

Shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 99
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 75
    [4] => 15
    [5] => 45
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The guys in the comments are probably right to give you a hard time (especially for not showing what you tried), but the interviewer was probably looking for something like this:

```
$my_arr = array(2, 45, 15, 75, 12, 99);
sort($my_arr); //order it from smallest to largest
$new_array = array();
while(count($my_arr)>0){ //while there are any items in the array
    $new_array[] = array_shift($my_arr); //get the first item and remove it
    if (count($my_arr) > 0){ //if there is a last element, get that and remove it
        $new_array[] = array_pop($my_arr);  
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Or, you could approach it without the `array_shift/pop` functions, in case those specific PHP functions aren't something you know:

```
$my_arr = array(2, 45, 15, 75, 12, 99);
sort($my_arr); //order it from smallest to largest

$new_array = array();
$total_elements = count($my_arr);
for($i=0;$i<$total_elements;$i++){
    if (!isset($my_arr[$i])){break;} //there's nothing left to do
    $new_array[] =  $my_arr[$i];
    if (isset($my_arr[$total_elements-$i])){
        $new_array[] =  $my_arr[$total_elements-$i];
        unset($my_arr[$total_elements-$i]); //remove the tail one
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: I did try, i just didn't post it in the question. I walked the interviewer thru my thought process. array_shift/pop never came to my mind at the interview so i was stuck halfway.

Answer (score 0):

### Easiest would be:

Sort this array `$my_arr = array(2, 45, 15, 75, 12, 99)` using `sort($my_arr);`

and generate new array named `$sorted = array()`

```
for($i = 0; $i < $size / 2; $i++) {
    $sorted[] = $my_arr[$i]; // Smallest....to..Largest

    if(count($sorted) === $size) break; // Stop if array is already sorted
    $sorted[] = $my_arr[$size - $i - 1]; // and largest to smallest.
}
```

This way we could keep the original array as it is. And can get a updated zigzag sorted array.